# MySql improve GROUP BY ORDER BY query with index

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I have a table like this:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║  product     ║ date      ║
╠════╬══════════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ P1           ║ 2020-08-01║
║  2 ║ P2           ║ 2020-08-01║
║  3 ║ P2           ║ 2020-08-03║
║  4 ║ P3           ║ 2020-08-04║
╚════╩══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

the goal is to query how many products have been sold per day, so the query is:

```
SELECT `date`, COUNT(id) AS `totalProductsSoldOnDate` 
FROM products 
GROUP BY `date` 
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

The output is:

```
   date        totalProductsSoldOnDate
2020-08-01 |         2
2020-08-03 |         1
2020-08-04 |         1
```

Ok. Now let us suppose we have a scenario with **several** records and this query has to be run **several times per day**, we need to care about performance now in order to retrive the results as fast as possible.

As far as I know, in a situation like this literature recommends to place an **index** on the column involved in the GROUP BY and ORDER BY, in this case *date*.

At this point the question is: **is this the correct solution?**

Moreover, assuming placing the index is fine:

1. Which is the most efficient index for a scenario like this, and why?
2. More important: how an index may increase performance? Even with an index on date I need to scan all the rows on a table, or I'm missing something?

Comment: you really are going to run this for all dates?  usually reports like this would only be interested in a particular date range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a *secondary* `INDEX(date, id)` would work faster than as `PRIMARY KEY`.  This is because the BTree that must be scanned is smaller.

To make the task significantly faster, summarize each day's data that night:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

In this case, let's look at what you have:

```
WHERE -- not present
GROUP BY -- just date
ORDER BY -- matches the GROUP BY
the whole query mentions only `date` and `id`
```

Let's try to build an optimal index:

1. Deal with `WHERE` -- nothing to do.  (OK to continue)
2. Add all the `GROUP BY` columns:  `INDEX(date,...)`  (OK to continue)
3. Since the `ORDER BY` matches, nothing to do.  (OK to continue)
4. Consider making a "covering index".  That is, add all the rest of the columns needed anywhere in the query.  (But don't make the index "too" big.)  `INDEX(date, id)`

By "OK to continue", I mean that there was not a brick wall stopping us:

- 2 range tests, non-sargeable expressions, etc, in `WHERE`
- `GROUP BY` list conflicting with `WHERE` (not the case here)
- `ORDER BY` missing ASC and DESC, or disagreeing with `GROUP BY`.

In a `JOIN` with, mentioning more than one table in `WHERE` (etc) is a brick wall.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for putting "date" before "id"?
Thanks!

Comment: @warcode360 - I added a lot to my Answer.  Do you have another query to analyze?  There are a lot of subtle issues that are not included in this Answer.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive reply! This query was ok to understand these principles, yet I understand there is a lot more about this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Make your primary key (date, id) and make your table InnoDB. That will still require a full table scan (because you had no WHERE clause), but at least it should avoid a filesort.

If you want to go faster than that, create a materialised view that contains the desired output an keep it current using triggers on the product table. Then you will be able to run something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mv_name ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: Thanks. The mv approach is very convenient.